# Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed

Tags: java, android, adapter, android-glide

Im trying to load profile image with Glide but when I run it throw a null url

```
W/Glide: Load failed for
http://aplikasi.muanetoraya.com/jaih/uploads/null with size [240x240]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(http://aplikasi.muanetoraya.com/jaih/uploads/null)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
      Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed,
class java.io.InputStream, REMOTE
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(http://aplikasi.muanetoraya.com/jaih/uploads/null)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetch failed
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(http://aplikasi.muanetoraya.com/jaih/uploads/null)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
          Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://aplikasi.muanetoraya.com/jaih/uploads/null I/Glide: Root cause (1 of 1)
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://aplikasi.muanetoraya.com/jaih/uploads/null
```

Here is my code:

```
BindingAdapters.java

public final class BindingAdapters {

    @BindingAdapter({"app:profile_url"})
    public static void loadProfileImage(ImageView view, String profileUrl) {
        new GlideLoader(view.getContext()).loadWithCircleCrop("http://aplikasi.muanetoraya.com/jaih/uploads/" + profileUrl, view);
    }

    @BindingAdapter({"app:image_url"})
    public static void loadImage(ImageView view, String profileUrl) {
        String url = "http://aplikasi.muanetoraya.com/jaih/uploads/" + profileUrl;
        new GlideLoader(view.getContext()).loadImage(url, view);
    }
```

and it throw error like this:

```
W/Glide: Load failed for http://aplikasi.muanetoraya.com/jaih/uploads/null with size [240x240]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(http://aplikasi.muanetoraya.com/jaih/uploads/null)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
      Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, REMOTE
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(http://aplikasi.muanetoraya.com/jaih/uploads/null)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetch failed
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(http://aplikasi.muanetoraya.com/jaih/uploads/null)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
          Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://aplikasi.muanetoraya.com/jaih/uploads/null
I/Glide: Root cause (1 of 1)
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://aplikasi.muanetoraya.com/jaih/uploads/null
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:255)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadDataWithRedirects(HttpUrlFetcher.java:102)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:56)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:100)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.startNextOrFail(MultiModelLoader.java:164)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.onLoadFailed(MultiModelLoader.java:154)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:62)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:100)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNextLoad(SourceGenerator.java:70)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:279)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:393)
```

Comment: It says it failed to load the resource , make sure you re retreiving the data correctly , make sure the images urls work fine

Comment: So `profileUrl` is null?

Answer (score 2):

> java.io.FileNotFoundException(http://aplikasi.muanetoraya.com/jaih/uploads/null)

means your

> profileUrl

is null and therefore the resource i this http://aplikasi.muanetoraya.com/jaih/uploads/null link is probably not available